# Weatherstripping for inswing exterior door with clearance problems. Clearance door sweep?

Tags: doors, energy-efficiency, weatherstripping

How would you weatherstrip this gap under an inswing exterior door?  The door threshold is not very high, and the door already drags a bit on the interior carpet, so many styles of door threshold are out.

The gap ranges from 1/4" to 1/2", and is curved over the threshold width.  Light is clearly visible under the gap.

A bottom threshold is possible, but Pemko #250V for example is way too high to fit (and as an extruded part wicks cold right from the outside to the inside, defeating the purpose somewhat).

What are options here?
[image: Low clearance inswing door weatherstrip]

Comment: I see what may be an adjustment rail in the center there. I'd try pulling that out and see if you can shim it up or replace it with a rubber seal. Also, "cold" isn't a thing and can't be wicked. Cold _air_ can flow, but that's not wicking. _Heat_ is a thing, and it _can_ be wicked (or _conducted_, more accurately).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to order one of these 3 choices but Pemko makes saddle thresholds that will raise the height from 1/4" to 1/2", depending which one you may go for. I checked their [catalog online](http://constructionbuildingcomponents.com/catalogs/catalog-pemko.pdf) and the numbers are 151, 170 or 166. This would give you a durable surface that would not wear out, but you will need to cut the door bottom, reseal it and add the sweep to the door leaf. If the original sill has a crown, the added threshold can be carefully shimmed flat so a new sweep will seal better.

There are "door shoes" in the catalog to aid in the sealing, but those are available at the local hardware store too.

Another alternative is to cut the door bottom off for clearance, rout a groove in the bottom of the door and set a drop threshold, but those are rather particular to set and get to work good.

Answer (score 0):

I've used mounted door sweeps for this before and it seemed to work well.

[image]

Comment: As noted above, a door sweep won't work because the door already touches the carpet.  The sweep would add 1/4" to 1/2" minimum, and the door would be unable to open or close.

Comment: It looks like there is a gap to me based on the visible shadow. If you attached it to the exterior of the door and made it just snug enough to block light, I would think it would be fine. FYI, they also make door sweeps with bristles instead of rubber blades.

Comment: The inswing door sweeps the carpet now.  Nothing can be added, or the door won't pen. It won't work.  I've opened the door, I know.

Answer (score 0):

My inclination is to install something on the threshold and, depending on the thickness you can find, you may have to trim the bottom of the door slightly.

You could try an under door threshold kit like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BD8LC0) but turn it over and screw it down to the threshold instead of the bottom of the door.

OR if the gap is not to big, try a bumper threshold like [this one](https://www.tmhardware.com/Bumper-Threshold-for-Pre-Hung-Outswing-Door-Aluminum-with-Seals-For-Sills.html?sku=PK165DT).

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar situation and used the expansion tape. This solved the hermetic problem.
https://sklep.grupamagnum.eu/pl/tasma-rozprezna-300pa-600pa-hannoband-hbd-15-3-5.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).